# SQL Server -Multiple rows in Sub Query

Tags: mysql, sql

This query working of single row but, i want to subtract multiple rows

```
SELECT(
(SELECT num1 from table1 where T_Type=2) - 
(SELECT num2 from table1 where T_Type=3))as
[SUBSTRACTION]
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, there are multiple records in table1 with `T_Type=2`, and multiple records in table1 with `T_Type=3`, and you want to retrieve a list of differences. Just how is SQL Server supposed to know how to 'pair' the records? In other words, what is the join condition?

Comment: There are same number of record.

Comment: Relations should be based on keys, not record numbers. Some background info might help. What kind of entity is table1? What are you trying to accomplish with your query?

Comment: Got Answer by SAGAR Gawande ----

Comment: select s.num1-i.num2 from (SELECT t1.num2 as 'num1', t1.C_ID  From table1 t1  where t1.T_Type=3)s inner join 
(SELECT t2.num2 as 'num2', t2.C_ID from table1 t2 where t2.T_Type=3 )i on s.C_ID=i.C_ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT t1.num1-t2.num2 from table1 t1,table1 t2 where t1.T_Type=2 and t2.T_Type=3
```

Comment: substract num1 - num2 for every row

Comment: I modified my answer.

Comment: can i substract one date difference and another is aggeregate function like

Comment: SELECT DATEDIFF(MM,t1.Date,GETDATE())- MAX(t2.num2)from table t1,table t2 where t1.T_Type=2 and T_Type=3 group by t2.S_ID

Comment: select s.num1-i.num2 from (SELECT t1.num2 as 'num1', t1.C_ID  From table1 t1  where t1.T_Type=3)s inner join 
(SELECT t2.num2 as 'num2', t2.C_ID from table1 t2 where t2.T_Type=3 )i on s.C_ID=i.C_ID

Answer (score 0):

How about SUMming the num's based on the types and subtracting these results, like this:

```
SELECT (  
(SELECT SUM(num1) FROM table1 WHERE T_Type = 2) -  
(SELECT SUM(num2) FROM table1 WHERE T_Type = 3))
```

Comment: Substract every coloumn row

Comment: My friend got that answer SAGAR GAWANDE

Comment: select s.num1-i.num2 from (SELECT t1.num2 as 'num1', t1.C_ID  From table1 t1  where t1.T_Type=3)s inner join 
(SELECT t2.num2 as 'num2', t2.C_ID from table1 t2 where t2.T_Type=3 )i on s.C_ID=i.C_ID